# Pros and cons of given cassandra schema

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I have this schema to store a `post` and its comment together in same table:

```
CREATE TABLE post ( 
  post_id int,
  access_key text,
  comment_id int,
  title text,
  comments FROZEN <type_comment>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((post_id, access_key), comment_id)
);

CREATE TYPE ks_test.type_comment (
  id int,
  content text
);
```

**here is a sample data**

```
post_id | access_key | comment_id | comments                 | title
---------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------
       1 | about_post |          1 |                     null | this is post
       1 |   comments |          2 | {id: 2, content: 'cmn1'} |         null
       1 |   comments |          3 | {id: 3, content: 'cmn2'} |         null
       1 |   comments |          4 | {id: 4, content: 'cmn3'} |         null
```

I am using this schema so that i have to access only one table to get a `post` and its comment. What will the pros & cons of this schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really thats fine and will work if you can figure out how to fill in the id fields.

I think the `comment_id` and `id` in `type_comment` is redundant. Can replace entire `comments` column with `content`.

Personally I would replace post_id with a time uuid since there is no auto incrementing thing id in Cassandra. Auto incrementing globally unique identifiers in a distributed environment is difficult. There are some things out there to do it for you but really, just using a time uuid/random uuid is the easiest.

```
CREATE TABLE post ( 
  post_id uuid,
  access_key text,
  comment_id timeuuid,
  title text,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((post_id, access_key), comment_id)
);
```

If want to grab it by date can do something like

```
CREATE TABLE post ( 
  year int,
  month int,
  access_key text,
  comment_id timeuuid,
  title text,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((access_key, year, month), comment_id)
);
```

then you can grab by month and can also use ranges to grab within periods of that month. Could also make a "time_bucket" to replace year/month as an iso time string like "2016-01-01 00:00:00" than you can change bucketing easier (ie months, days etc).

Comment: what i wanted to know here is that ? in some row there will be `null` column value as you can see in output, so i number of records will increase those `null` value will also increase. Is that a problem?

Comment: only the partition/clustering keys need to be set (providing no materialized view/indexing on others), the absence of the other ones just means less used disk space.

Comment: In your opinion what are the pros & cons of this schema approach?

Comment: PROs - it will work and partitions data well. CONs - requires something awkward for id generations and has some redundant data (but disk space is cheap so meh).

Comment: Does it make any difference if the value of all partition or cluster key are same ?

Comment: if the partition + clustering keys are all exact same they will override each other. but there can be a lot of different rows within a partition. Have you gone through the [datastax academy stuff](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling)? Theres good info there.

Comment: no no what i mean is let say i have two different row. first row's `partition + clustering` both is `x` and second row's `partition + clustering` is `Y`.

Comment: oh, its a little redundant but no big deal. If they are *always* the same just get rid of the clustering.